# How to add code templates for servlets in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, ide

How to add code templates for servlets in eclipse ?

I know that we can add code templates for new java files in

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates.
```

I have to add some details like date, name, copyright etc for each java file.
I am able to achieve the same using code templates for java files but the same is not working when I create servlets.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: no I did not. not using servlets now..so did not look further..

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates > Comments > Files > Edit

make the changes and Apply 
changes will reflect in each file you create.

Comment: I have done the same. This will work for java files , but not working when I create servlets.

Comment: Then may be you need to import your custom temples  using xml.